# Disable submit button until username lookup is valid

Tags: jquery

I have a script that check to see if a "username" is valid. This works fine but what I would like to do is disable the form submit button until the check is valid. The script I have so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#feedback').load('check_username.php').show();

    $('#login').keyup(function(){
        $.post('check_username.php', { login: form2.login.value },
        function(result) {
            $('#feedback').html(result).show();         
        });
    });
});
```

The "check_username.php" script is:

```
if($totalRows_LoginLookup==1) {
    echo "The login name is already registered";
    $Hide_SaveButton = 1;
}else if($totalRows_RoomLookup==0) {
    echo "The login name is  valid";
    $Hide_SaveButton = 0;
}
```

Is there a way to use the returned value of $Hide_SaveButton" in the jQuery script to dsiable the submit button.

Any help would be great. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In check_username.php:

```
if($totalRows_LoginLookup == 1) {
    echo 'registered';
    exit;
}

echo 'available';
```

And in the front-end, you can do it using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feedback').load('check_username.php').show();

    $('#login').keyup(function(){
        $.post('check_username.php', { login: form2.login.value }, function(result) {
            if(result == 'registered') {
                $('input[type=image]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                return;
            }

            $('input[type=image]').prop('disabled', false); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sadly it does not work. My submit button is an image "<input type="image" src="nav/images/save_button.png"  value="Insert record" />" but even when I change it for a normal submit button it does not disable it. Any ideas?

Comment: You can `console.log` the response of the request and check if the result is `registered`.

Comment: The console log:SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement. TypeError: Spry.Widget.ValidationSelect is not a constructor. I can't see where the missing } should be

Comment: @IagoMelanias & DCJones: Hi! Instead of `$('input[type=image]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`, maybe an `event.PreventDefault()` could be used on the button, so that clicking on the button does nothing, and when the username is valid, the button could be enabled via: `$('input[type=image]').unbind('submit').submit()`

Comment: I believe that is not the problem. Disable the submit button would work anyway, as you can  see here: http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/1ma1zdf8/.